# MySQL Syntax Error With Stored Procedures

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I must be missing something simple because I can't figure out what is causing my script to fail.
Below is the stored procedure I've written:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `Search_contacts`(IN `in_owner_id` INT,
    IN `in_first_name` VARCHAR(255))
 IF in_first_name IS NOT NULL THEN
     SELECT * FROM `contacts`
     WHERE `owner_id` = in_owner_id AND `first_name` LIKE in_first_name;
END IF;
```

When I try and execute this on my MySQL server I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 5
```

I'd like to know what is causing this error and why so I can avoid it again.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding "BEGIN", "END" and "DELIIMITER", like this:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `Search_contacts`(IN `in_owner_id` INT,
    IN `in_first_name` VARCHAR(255))
BEGIN
    IF in_first_name IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT * FROM `contacts`
        WHERE `owner_id` = in_owner_id AND `first_name` LIKE in_first_name;
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: I had a feeling I was forgetting something simple, thank you! Is it best practice to always include "DELIMITER", "BEGIN" and "END"?